# SHA256 Hash to float number

Tags: javascript, sha256, cryptojs

I've been trying to convert a hash to a float number, so far I have only achieved to generate a number from it.

How would I convert a SHA256 Hash to a float number ranging from 0.0 to 1.0?

How I got a number,

```
var hash = 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
var number = hash.substr(0, 8);
number = parseInt(number, 16);
number = Math.abs(number) % 11;
console.log('Number (0 - 10): ' + number);
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible?  A float by definition has some degree of unpreciseness (had to make that up) associated with how it's stored.  Even if you could convert the hash, it's entirely possible that it won't be an accurate representation anymore.  What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @roelofs "imprecision" :-) --- To OP: You could check out the crypto StackExchange forum, for example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17990/sha256-output-to-0-99-number-range

Comment: @Mörre - that's the one - thanks!  Great link, although I'm not sure what he's after.  In theory, with a big enough mantissa and exponent, he could just divide the hash by a really large number...

Comment: @Mörre check the code I edited, that's how I managed to get a number, if I can get a integer I surely should be able to get a float, or..?

Comment: You could create a hash from the 256 bits of the SHA256 to the bits of a Javascript `Number` and assign those using a `TypedArray`. You would definitely lose information, since the nr. of bits in a `Number` is a lot less! You may as well simply use every 4th bit. Actually a bit more, since only some of the 64 bits in a Javascript `Number` can be used here. -- Check out this explanation of the JS number format: http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html Or just use the first 52 bits, it should not matter **which** bits you throw away.

Comment: @Mörre is correct.  If you're happy losing a lot of information (and therefore, make using the SHA256 hash mostly pointless in the first place), it would work.  If you still need an accurate representation of the hash, this is not the way to go.

Comment: @roelofs I just need the hash to always generate the same float number, I don't mind losing the information, it's used to show a number wasn't modified by anyone.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens - That's a potential problem with floats.  Because it essentially approximates a number, it's possible that it may not be accurate enough to even do that with a high degree of accuracy.  Why not just use a much smaller hash (like MD5)?

Comment: @roelofs I'd only use the first bit of the hash.

Comment: @MartijnEbbens - depending on how much of the first bit of the hash is used, and the type of modifications you're expecting, you're potentially making your collision space VERY small, which may negate what you're trying to do.

Comment: There are many "reasonable" ways to achieve this (without any further constrains/requirements). One option is to do byte-by-byte comparison against the "largest" hash value, that is, "ffff .... ffff" (32 bytes), and you end up getting 32 numbers (e.g., each ranging from 0 to 1, for instance). You can get a single number doing any reasonable arithmetic to get the final number ranging 0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var hash = 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
var number = 0.0;
for(let i=0;i<hash.length;i++) {
    number += parseInt(hash.charAt(i), 16) / 16;
}
number /= hash.length;
console.log('number = ' + number);
```

In this example, I give the equal weight to each of the 32 numbers (which seems reasonable since a hash is really not a number). But, you can give different weights to different bytes. For instance, you can give a weight of 2^31 to the first byte, and 2^30 for the second byte, etc. and normalize the final number accordingly.

Edit: You can also do the comparison for multiple bytes at a time. E.g., 16 numbers with each coming from 2 bytes, or 8 numbers with each coming from 4 bytes, etc. As you increase the "unit" size, the resulting final number will have a "higher fidelity" to the original hash value.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Mörre contains the best answer. Simply take the first 52-bits of the hash (or any convenient 52 bits of the hash) and assign it to a javascript number. A 52-bit integer can be stored exactly as an IEEE 754 double. Then simply divide the number by 2<sup>52</sup>, which should only effect the exponent bits of the number. The result is a floating point number x, 0 <= x < 1, with as much entropy as is possible given the constraints.